# PHP Symfony2 Doctrine PDO_PGSQL binding variables

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I have this query in my PHP code:

```
select * from book where title ~* '\mkeyword'; /* \m matches only at the beginning of a word */
```

keyword is user input. How can I rewrite the query to use binding variables?
When I do this:

```
select * from book where title ~* :keyword;
```

and then:

```
$stmt->bindValue('keyword', "\m".$keyword);
```

after prepare statement,
I get \\m in the query and the query won't work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

For a parameter named `:keyword`, you must also use the same name - inluding colon, see Examples section of [`PDOStatement::bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindValue(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

So in your case, it should be

```
$stmt->bindValue(':keyword', "\m" . $keyword);
```

---

As an alternative, you can also give an array to [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
$stmt->execute(array(':keyword' => "\m" . $keyword));
```